# Installing Windows 10 to used HDD

Tags: windows, installation, bios

I'm trying to install Windows 10 from a USB stick ISO to a tower computer with a new Asus MoBo Rog Strix X570-E with Zen 7 but used hard drives. The BIOS does not see a compatible drive to do the installation.

Must I install to a new HDD or is there a work around to install it on one with data? i.e. BIOS settings.

Do I need to install drivers to the HDD I want to use?

Answer (score 0):

The older hard drive may be incompatible with the newer system. Also check the hard drive for errors (numerous hard drive test apps available).

Myself, I would not spend time installing a new system on an old drive. Too much chance of problems early down the road.

Assuming you do need a new drive, get a good quality SSD drive for the computer as this will be much faster as well.

Finally, if the new board has TPM V2, you can likely install Windows 11. This will be better as Windows 10 is good only until some time in 2025.

Answer (score 0):

Could you please tell me if the HDD is fully empty or there are some old files in it. Because there are very less chances of compatibility issue of a drive, I would suggest you to check for BIOS Settings and see if the Boot Order is correctly configured or not.

If you want to install Windows 10 from USB then 1st priority should be set to USB Flash and 2nd priority to HDD or SSD.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: Thank you for answering my query. Yes, one of the problems was the order of boot in the bios. The second issue was the USB image I was using. I reloaded an image from a Microsoft site and no installing issues at all. Thanks to all that participated.

Comment: Great your issue was fixed. It would be better if you could upvote or close this question by accepting the solution.